# How can I make a variation limits, do not exceed a specific value

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Now I am facing a problem that making a variation does not exceed a specific value.
I will describe in details below.

```
using CP;

int a = 4;
int b = 3;
int c = 5;

range arange = 1..a;
range brange = 1..b;
range crange = 1..c;

dvar boolean x[a][b][c];
dvar int y[b][c] in 1..4;
```

---

In this case, I'm trying to calculate

```
y[b][c+1] = x[a][b][c] - 1 + y[b][c];
```

However, all y[e][t] are in 1 to 4.

I mean

> if y[b][c] >= 4, then y[b][c] == 4,  and if y[b][c] <= 1, then y[b][c] == 1

like that.

---

So, Now I trying to do this

```
y[b][c+1] == max(min(x[a][b][c] -1 + y[b][c], 4), 1);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [minl](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/tlr_oplf_minl.html) and [maxl](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/tlr_oplf_maxl.html) instead:

```
y[b][c+1] == maxl(minl(2 * x[a][b][c] -1 + y[b][c], 4), 1);
```